# Dynamically set SRS_DOMAIN

Tags: postfix, spf

I have a mailserver forwarding mail and using postsrsd for SRS.  Since postsrsd uses postfix's `mydomain` setting to alter the Return-Path, is there a way to set the SRS_DOMAIN for forwarded mail based on the recipient address instead of setting it statically?  Since the mailserver handles mail for several different domains, I'd like the return path to match the recipient's domain, not the hostname of the mailserver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No, it can't [due to the way PostSRSd is integrated with Postfix](https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd/blob/master/README.md).

Your idea is PostSRSd need to read the recipient address so it can rewrite based on it. Unfortunately PostSRSd uses `sender_canonical_maps` **to provide rewriting scheme**. With this scheme PostSRSd only get get the sender address only. AFAIK, postfix doesn't have feature to rewriting sender address based on recipient address. You can try to read the [official docs](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html).

Comment: I also noticed that the OP already [fill the issue tracker](https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd/issues/31) on PostSRSd repository.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying masegaloeh.  Yes, I figured it was worth a go after posting here to contact the dev and see if there was any chance to make this happen.